# Possible rendering bug for code in markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, code-formatting

I was traveling stackoverflow, when I've encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586284/finding-prime-numbers-with-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-originally-is-there-a-bet) and at the very end of it:

[image]

I thought ok, maybe somebody just forget to write `return primes; }`, but it appears it **is written** in the original text:

[image]

Moreover, it is correctly rendered in preview:

[image]

Is it bug? I'm on OSX 10.8 and using Chrome 25.0.1364.152.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was from Feb 2009, when we had a brief period of time when this render bug occurred (mostly happening with long posts - they got truncated in the render process). We save the rendered HTML and this is what is used for display - this is not updated unless the post is.

There are some old posts like the above that display the issue - any edit re-renders and saves the updated HTML.

Comment: Edited and it fixed it. +1.